# layoutChildren being called infinitely - JavaFX 2

Tags: java, javafx-2, label, pane

I'm having a layout problem when adding a Label to a Pane which is added to another Pane.

Like in this example:

```
public class MyClass extends Pane {

  private final Pane myPane;

  public MyClass() {

    this.myPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty);
    this.myPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty);

    this.getChildren().add(this.myPane);
  }

  @Override
  layoutChildren() {

    this.foo();
  }

  private void foo() {

    this.myPane.getChildren().add(new Label("foo"));
  }

}
```

The problem is that it just keeping calling layoutChildren infinitely. One thing that is weird is that if I add a Text instead of a Label, the "problem" doesn't occour.

I've checked every node sizes and they don't change. It seens to me that someone is expanding and for that the layout is called, but I just can't find where.

Is there something trivial that I'm missing?

Comment: Why a Pane `myPane` inside a class `MyClass` which is already extending a Pane. Moreovr, binding the width and height ? You should shed some light on what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I tried to extract the main problem here, unfortunately the code is  very complex and I can't post it here. It really doesn't make sense to create a Pane inside a Pane here, but in reality it does :)

Answer (score 1):

layoutChildren is called constantly by the QuantumToolkit. The entire scene graph is traversed and each node has this method called during the lifetime of the application. It never ends.

*From Oracle:*

**Threads**

The system runs two or more of the following threads at any given time.

JavaFX application thread: This is the primary thread used by JavaFX application developers. Any “live” scene, which is a scene that is part of a window, must be accessed from this thread. A scene graph can be created and manipulated in a background thread, but when its root node is attached to any live object in the scene, that scene graph must be accessed from the JavaFX application thread. This enables developers to create complex scene graphs on a background thread while keeping animations on 'live' scenes smooth and fast. The JavaFX application thread is a different thread from the Swing and AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), so care must be taken when embedding JavaFX code into Swing applications.
Prism render thread: This thread handles the rendering separately from the event dispatcher. It allows frame N to be rendered while frame N +1 is being processed. This ability to perform concurrent processing is a big advantage, especially on modern systems that have multiple processors. The Prism render thread may also have multiple rasterization threads that help off-load work that needs to be done in rendering.
Media thread: This thread runs in the background and synchronizes the latest frames through the scene graph by using the JavaFX application thread.

**Pulse**

A pulse is an event that indicates to the JavaFX scene graph that it is time to synchronize the state of the elements on the scene graph with Prism. A pulse is throttled at 60 frames per second (fps) maximum and is fired whenever animations are running on the scene graph. Even when animation is not running, a pulse is scheduled when something in the scene graph is changed. For example, if a position of a button is changed, a pulse is scheduled.

When a pulse is fired, the state of the elements on the scene graph is synchronized down to the rendering layer. A pulse enables application developers a way to handle events asynchronously. This important feature allows the system to batch and execute events on the pulse.

Layout and CSS are also tied to pulse events. Numerous changes in the scene graph could lead to multiple layout or CSS updates, which could seriously degrade performance. The system automatically performs a CSS and layout pass once per pulse to avoid performance degradation. Application developers can also manually trigger layout passes as needed to take measurements prior to a pulse.

The Glass Windowing Toolkit is responsible for executing the pulse events. It uses the high-resolution native timers to make the execution.

---

Layout Children is called 60 times/second on all nodes that have been altered in some way. So if a child deep in the graph is changed, all parents of that child will have layoutChildren called.

Answer (score 0):

Your overriden layout method invokes foo, which in turn causes a new Label to be added. Unless I am mistaken, this will cause another layout pass to be initiated, which in turn will add a new Label, thus causing your infinite cycle.

Comment: That was my first thought. But the thing is: if I add it directly to the class ( this.getChildren.add() ), the problem doesn't occour. If I add a Text node, a ImageView or any other component, the problem doesn't occour. It seems to happen only when I add to the secondary pane a Labeled node.